# Not equals query is so slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like that:

```
SELECT * , (
( 1584392725 ) - ( suprayts.time )
) AS timeDiff
FROM (
`suprayts`
)

WHERE  `suprayts`.`is_deleted` = '0'
AND `suprayts`.`is_approved` =1
AND `suprayts`.`username` != 'rayben1'
AND `suprayts`.`time` >1584306325
ORDER BY `suprayts`.`is_boosted_by_user` DESC , `suprayts`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 10
```

This query runs very slow (avg 0.2 seconds), if i delete the following line:

```
AND `suprayts`.`username` != 'rayben1'
```

It runs 10x faster. (avg 0.02 secs) How can i speed up this query?

My indexes:

[image]

Explain:

[image]

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `suprayts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `suprayt_photo` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `endTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datetext` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `like_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dislike_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_approved` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `is_deleted` enum('1','0') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_end_notification_sent` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `open_vote` enum('0','1') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `boost` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_boosted_by_user` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_3` (`username`,`suprayt_photo`),
  KEY `id` (`id`,`time`,`is_approved`,`is_deleted`),
  KEY `username` (`username`,`is_deleted`),
  KEY `username_2` (`username`,`datetext`),
  KEY `id_2` (`id`,`username`,`time`,`is_approved`,`is_deleted`),
  KEY `username_4` (`username`,`time`,`is_approved`,`is_deleted`),
  KEY `ix1` (`id`,`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=130789 ;
```

Comment: have you done a `describe <sql>` to see how the database engine would execute your query?

Comment: How many rows does the logic on username filter out?

Comment: Avg 140k rows filtering

Comment: @Ja͢ck i added explain, please see my edit

Comment: you don't need to take screenshots, btw; could you also do a `show create table` so that we can see how many indexes you've got on it?

Comment: @Ja͢ck updated my question

Comment: without getting too much into this, there are a lot of useless indexes in your table; the ones that have the primary key can be thrown out ... then i would create one whereby `time` is the last field of your index, so that you can take advantage of range queries; e.g. `is_approved, is_deleted, time`

Comment: But i am using that indexes also for different queries

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the SQL pre-compiler if one is being used, or the SQL itself, possible it is sensitive to the order of the query "where" clause not being in DB key order and it is not using the index and instead doing a sequential scan? Just to eliminate the possibility, try putting the WHERE items in the DB index key order.

Answer (score -1):

USE NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT * , (
( 1584392725 ) - ( suprayts.time )
) AS timeDiff
FROM (
`suprayts`
)

WHERE  `suprayts`.`is_deleted` = '0'
AND `suprayts`.`is_approved` =1
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT x.no FROM (SELECT 1 AS no) x WHERE `suprayts`.`username` = 'rayben1'
)
AND `suprayts`.`time` >1584306325
ORDER BY `suprayts`.`is_boosted_by_user` DESC , `suprayts`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 10
```